# Confusion about output of program with virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance, name-lookup

I'm new to c++ and have been experimenting with virtual inheritance. But there is something that really confuses me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {int m = 5005;};
struct B : A {};
struct C : virtual B {};
struct D : virtual B {int m = 6006;};
struct E : C, D {};

int main () {
   E e;
   e.m = 303;

   cout << "e.A::m = " << e.A::m << endl;
   cout << "e.D::m = " << e.D::m << endl;
   cout << "e.m = " << e.m << endl;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
e.A::m = 5005
e.D::m = 303
e.m = 303
```

Now, what confuses me is `e.D::m = 303`. Shouldn't it be 6006? I know there are already quite a few questions to virtual inheritance but no one really explained why this is happening.
I also think I've found another program that shows the same "problem".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct S {int m = 101;};
struct A : virtual S {int m = 202;};
struct B : virtual S {int m = 303;};
struct C : virtual A, virtual B {int m = 404;};
struct D : C {};
struct E : virtual A, virtual B, D {};

int main () {
   E e;
   e.m = 10;

   cout << "e.S::m = " << e.S::m << endl;
   cout << "e.A::m = " << e.A::m << endl;
   cout << "e.B::m = " << e.B::m << endl;
   cout << "e.C::m = " << e.C::m << endl;
   cout << "e.m = " << e.m << endl;
}
```

Where the output is

```
e.S::m = 101
e.A::m = 202
e.B::m = 303
e.C::m = 10
e.m = 10
```

And also here `e.C::m=10` confuses me. Can someone please explain what's going on here? I acually thought I understood the principle of virtual inheritance.

Comment: You have to pour over the [name lookup logic](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.member.lookup) to figure out why that's happening.

Comment: Or to get a quick intuition, print (or inspect in your debugger) `&e.m`, `&e.A::m`, `&e.D::m`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the paragraph [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Member_function_definition) explains this behavior:

> Either way, when examining the bases from which the class is derived, the following rules, sometime referred to as dominance in virtual inheritance, are followed:
>
> A *lookup set* is constructed, which consists of the declarations and
>   the subobjects in which these declarations were found.
>   Using-declarations are replaced by the members they represent and type
>   declarations, including injected-class-names are replaced by the types
>   they represent. If C is the class in whose scope the name was used, C
>   is examined first. If the list of declarations in C is empty, lookup
>   set is built for each of its direct bases Bi (recursively applying
>   these rules if Bi has its own bases). Once built, the lookup sets for
>   the direct bases are merged into the lookup set in C as follows
>
> - if the set of declarations in Bi is empty, it is discarded
> - if the lookup set of C built so far is empty, it is replaced by the lookup set of Bi
> - if every subobject in the lookup set of Bi is a base of at least one of
>     the subobjects already added to the lookup set of C, the lookup set of
>     Bi is discarded.
> - if every subobject already added to the lookup set of
>     C is a base of at least one subobject in the lookup set of Bi, then
>     the lookup set of C is discarded and replaced with the lookup set of
>     Bi
> - otherwise, if the declaration sets in Bi and in C are different,
>     the result is an ambiguous merge: the new lookup set of C has an
>     invalid declaration and a union of the subobjects ealier merged into C
>     and introduced from Bi. This invalid lookup set may not be an error if
>     it is discarded later.
> - otherwise, the new lookup set of C has the
>     shared declaration sets and the union of the subobjects ealier merged
>     into C and introduced from Bi

The example helps illustrate the logic here:

```
struct X { void f(); };
struct B1: virtual X { void f(); };
struct B2: virtual X {};
struct D : B1, B2 {
    void foo() {
        X::f(); // OK, calls X::f (qualified lookup)
        f(); // OK, calls B1::f (unqualified lookup)
// C++11 rules: lookup set for f in D finds nothing, proceeds to bases
//  lookup set for f in B1 finds B1::f, and is completed
// merge replaces the empty set, now lookup set for f in C has B1::f in B1
//  lookup set for f in B2 finds nothing, proceeds to bases
//    lookup for f in X finds X::f
//  merge replaces the empty set, now lookup set for f in B2 has X::f in X
// merge into C finds that every subobject (X) in the lookup set in B2 is a base
// of every subobject (B1) already merged, so the B2 set is discareded
// C is left with just B1::f found in B1
// (if struct D : B2, B1 was used, then the last merge would *replace* C's 
//  so far merged X::f in X because every subobject already added to C (that is X)
//  would be a base of at least one subobject in the new set (B1), the end
//  result would be the same: lookup set in C holds just B1::f found in B1)
    }
};
```

TL;DR: Because `e.m = 303;` is an *unqualified lookup*, the compiler will recursively look up the inheritance tree for matching declarations.  In this case I think it would first find `A::m`, but would replace this with `D::m` after seeing that `D` has `A` as an indirect base class.  So `e.m` ends up resolving to `e.D::m`.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering you to your first question. You have just over write the value of m in your class D.

```
 E e;
 e.m = 303;//you just over write the value 6006, just comment out this line and check

  cout << "e.A::m = " << e.A::m << endl;
  cout << "e.D::m = " << e.D::m << endl;
  cout << "e.m = " << e.m << endl;
```

Here B inherited A and B has been inherited to C and D virtually so only one copy of B will be available in E finally. So you can access data member `m` of class A through A::m and your e.m and e.D::m is accessing the same data member i.e. `m` of class D.

Now see below some interesting results:-

```
    //e.m = 303;

    cout << "e.A::m = " << e.A::m << endl;
    cout << "e.D::m = " << e.D::m << endl;
    cout << "e.m = " << e.m << endl;

    e.m = 303;//over write D::m;

    cout << "e.A::m = " << e.A::m << endl;
    cout << "e.D::m = " << e.D::m << endl;
    cout << "e.m = " << e.m << endl;

    e.E::m = 101;//over write D::m

    cout << "e.A::m = " << e.A::m << endl;
    cout << "e.D::m = " << e.D::m << endl;
    cout << "e.m = " << e.m << endl;

    e.B::m = 202;//over write A::m through B

    cout << "e.A::m = " << e.A::m << endl;
    cout << "e.D::m = " << e.D::m << endl;
    cout << "e.m = " << e.m << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The virtual classes 'bubble up' to the top of the hierarchy, but they are considered after the non-virtual classes during lookup.

---

### Example 1

`struct E : C, D {};` becomes (virtual classes in round brackets):

```
E
  C
  D
 (B) - bubbled up to E from other classes.
```

Next we look at what is in C and D:

```
E
  C      <-- continue lookup
   (B)   <-- will not continue to look for m here yet
  D
   (B)   <-- will not continue to look for m here yet either
    m    <-- m found during unqualified lookup
 (B)     <-- may continue to look for m here, but already found it above
```

---

### Example 2

`struct E : virtual A, virtual B, D {};` becomes:

```
E
  D  - first non-virtual class at top level
 (A)
 (B)
 (S) - bubbled up from other classes.
```

Next we look at what is in D:

```
E
  D      <-- continue lookup
    C    <-- continue lookup
      m  <-- m found during unqualified lookup
 (A)     <-- no further lookup, m already found
 (B)     <-- no further lookup, m already found
 (S)     <-- no further lookup, m already found
```